# Dá mensagem de sucesso que salvo, não mensagem de erro, mas no banco não está salvo - jsf

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, cdi

O meu código está dando mensagem de sucesso em salvar o registro, mas na realidade ele não está salvando, já verifiquei no banco de dados, não está gerando mensagem de erro, e apresenta está o código todo certo, o que será que se passa para isso acontecer?

Minha classe Bean

```
package br.com.terezinha.imobiliaria.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import br.com.terezinha.imobiliaria.model.Cidade;
import br.com.terezinha.imobiliaria.repository.Cidades;
import br.com.terezinha.imobiliaria.services.CadastroCidadeService;
import br.com.terezinha.imobiliaria.util.FacesUtil;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroCidadeBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Cidade cidade;


    @Inject
    private CadastroCidadeService cadastroCidadeService;


    @Inject
    private Cidades cidades;

    public CadastroCidadeBean() {
        cidade = new Cidade();
    }

//    public void inicializar() {
//        System.out.println("iniciaando ........");
//        if (FacesUtil.isNotPostback()) {
//            todasCidades = cidades.raizesC();
//        }
//    }
//    

    public void salvar(){
        this.cidade = cadastroCidadeService.salvar(cidade);
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Cidade salvo com sucesso");
    }

    public Cidade getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }


    public Cidades getCidades() {
        return cidades;
    }

    public void setCidades(Cidades cidades) {
        this.cidades = cidades;
    }

}
```

Minha classe que inseri o registro;

```
package br.com.terezinha.imobiliaria.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import br.com.terezinha.imobiliaria.model.Cidade;

public class Cidades implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public Cidade porId(Long id) {
        return manager.find(Cidade.class, id);

    }


    public List<Cidade> raizesC(){
        return manager.createQuery("from Cidade order by nome", Cidade.class).getResultList();
    }



    public Cidade guardar(Cidade cidade) {
        return manager.merge(cidade);
    }



}
```

///////////////////////////////

```
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Inject
private Cidades cidades;


@Transactional
public  Cidade salvar(Cidade cidade){
    return cidades.guardar(cidade);
}
```

Minha pagina

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="titulo">Novo produto</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpo">



        <h:form>

            <h1>Nova Cidade</h1>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:button value="Novo" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar"  action="#{cadastroCidadeBean.salvar}" update="@form"/>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:button value="Pesquisa" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel"
                style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
                <p:outputLabel value="Nome da cidade" for="cidade" />
                <p:inputText id="cidade" size="20" maxlength="20"
                    value="#{cadastroCidadeBean.cidade.nome}" />


            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

O caminho do meu projeto no repositorio GitHub

https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Terezinha.Adm

fiz essas tentativas

tentativa um;

```
public void salvar(){
        this.cidade = cadastroCidadeService.salvar(this.cidade);
        System.out.println("valor da cidade no pacote controller  " + cidade.getNome());
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Cidade salvo com sucesso");
    }
```

tentativa dois;

```
public Cidade guardar(Cidade cidade) {
     cidade =  manager.merge(cidade);

     System.out.println("valor da cidade no pacote repositório " + cidade.getNome());
    return cidade;
}
```

tentativa três;

```
@Transactional
public Cidade salvar(Cidade cidade) {
    cidade = cidades.guardar(cidade);
    System.out.println("valor da cidade no pacote de negotios  " + cidade.getNome());
    return cidade;

}
```

resultador;

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
valor da cidade no pacote repositório Caruaru
valor da cidade no pacote de negotios  Caruaru
valor da cidade no pacote controller  Caruaru
```

Comment: É uma nova cidade com `id == null` certo? Tente com [`persist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-) ao invés de `merge` para fins de diagnóstico e poste para nós os comandos SQL gerados pelo Hibernate.

Comment: Outra coisa, seu código está utilizando *CDI Producers*, *Interceptors* e sua própria anotação `@Transactional` para fazer algo que um *container* EJB ou um *framework* como o Spring te dá de graça. Ainda que entenda o desejo de adotar uma estratégia *lightweight*, será que vale a pena tentar reinventar esse tipo de mecanismo?

Comment: o meu id não está igual a null. foi sem fundamento ter que oriantar trocar merger por persist porque na verdade você nem chegou a verificar direito meu código no GitHub. e outra ,não vejo nada de errado em usar  CDI Producers, Interceptors em anotação de @Transactional, você trata minha situação como semples. não é fácil para mim fazer em EJB e Spring, gostaria que pudesse me ajudar dentro da minha realidade.

Comment: Eu geralmente não respondo esse tipo de comentário, mas diria que se você espera que alguém vá fazer mais do que dar uma lida em diagonal no seu código final no Github sua expectativa está errada. Você é responsável por criar um [mvce](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), eu só estou tentando ensiná-lo a diagnosticar o problema, bem como mensurar prós e contras das suas decisões arquiteturais. De novo, dê uma olhada com calma no seu `CadastroClienteBean`, tem certeza que a `Cidade` tem `codigo` (o `id`) diferente de `null` quando você chama `cadastroCidadeBean.salvar`?

Comment: tudo bem, muito obrigado, vou verificar isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que pude notar pelo código, sua lógica de programação, está exibindo a mensagem de "Salvo" sem nem ao menos fazer um teste se este objeto realmente foi salvo. Provavelmente você está esquecendo de tratar as Transações com o Banco de Dados, pois não vi em seu código nenhum tratamento de Inicialização e Commit das transações com o banco de Dados. Experimente iniciar um transação e depois comitar no método em que é salvo a cidade.

Answer (score 0):

No metodo guardar da classe cidade esta faltando o

```
transaction.begin();
if(merge()){
  transaction.commit();
}else{
  transaction.rooback();
}
```

Comment: Olá Luiz, bem vindo ao [pt.so]! Podes [edit] a resposta para formatar melhor o código. Se fôr possível explicar um pouco mais a resposta seria excelente.